# Elasticsearch CCR: follower for large index fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch Cross Cluster Replication(CCR) as it's described at [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ccr-getting-started.html#ccr-getting-started-follower-index). Follower index creation works fine for leader indexes less than 2 Gb. If index size is bigger, follower index is created with status `paused` at CCR kibana tab and `red` at index management tab. When I run the same operation with curl PUT request, this error is shown:

```
{
  "error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
          "reason": "[_ccr_remote:_latest_/_latest_] cannot restore index [my_index_new] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"
        }
      ],
      "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
      "reason": "[_ccr_remote:_latest_/_latest_] cannot restore index [my_index_new] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"
    },
    "status": 500
  }
```

However, this errors tells nothing real, because there is no index `my_index_new` in local elasticsearch cluster before I run curl command.

Also, there is no any error at remote cluster logs.

Meanwhile, local elasticsearch log contains a lot of errors with such a string:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchTimeoutException: [internal:admin/ccr/restore/file_chunk/get] timed out after [1m]
```

Here is some description of my environment:

- 3 master and data nodes per cluster;
- SSD for both elasticsearch clusters;
- the same NTP server for both cluster;
- 50 GB RAM per cluster node;
- the size of `my_index_new` is 17 GB, it consists of 8 primary shards.

P.S. I've also asked this question at [elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ccr-follower-for-large-index-fails/258043), but with no result.